# No resource method found for GET, 405 error

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to test some microservices and first I need to get new token from the **Keycloak server** but when I am trying to run the below “**keyword**” I am getting the error: “**No resource method found for GET, return 405 with Allow header**”, but I don’t have any **GET method** on my keyword.

```
A valid token for "${client}" with secret "${client_secret}"
    ${auth} =    Create List    ${client}    ${client_secret}
    ${headers_dict} =    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded    Accept=application/json
    ${data_dict} =    Create Dictionary    grant_type=client_credentials
    Create Session    mysession    http://keycloak.${domain}    auth=${auth}
    ${resp}=    POST On Session    mysession    /auth/realms/gdp/protocol/openid-connect/token    headers=${headers_dict}    data=${data_dict}
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${resp.status_code}    200
    ${token}=    catenate    Bearer    ${resp.json()}[access_token]
    Set Suite Variable    ${EX_TOKEN}    ${token}
    Log    ${EX_TOKEN}
```

**output.log result:**
[image]

Comment: like i said on RF forum - this is most likely due to the fact that you are trying to get a token over HTTP - no sane implementation will give you working token over unencrypted transport. Eg, change the url to https://

Comment: Also, you had the error in rf forum as text and here you posted it as image .. On RF forum things could be more relax but posting images of of errors / code is really frowned upon.